# How to use my custom module data as product attribute?

Tags: magento2, database-schema

I have created a custom backend module(with eav attributes) in magento 2.3, where the customer can add some important data similar to this: number, number type, year.

I want to show these in a multiselect, as a product attribute. The appearance of this multiselect will be similar to the appearance of the category select.
Here is the example data and an image:

`123456 - oem - 2006
 123456 - oem - 2007
 789457 - oem - 2007`

[image]

Do I need to create a separate table for this, similar to `catalog_category_product`? Or the attributes will be saved as product attributes? I couldn't find much on this topic, the closest I got is [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133295/what-is-the-best-practice-way-in-magento-2-for-creating-many-to-many-relationshi).

Sorry if my question is a bit confusing, I am very new to magento, and i don't know the proper terminology yet.
It is important to note, that there will be thousands of these numbers, and the user has to be able to modify them in the backend.